# Is it possible to randomize the order of response options with radiobuttons in rshiny?

Tags: r, shiny, survey

Say for instance that I want to ask the question below and avoid ordering effects by randomizing. How can I do that in R Shiny?

```
radioButtons("knowledge1", 
                     label = "On which of the following the does the U.S. federal government currently spend the least?",
                     choices = c("Foreign aid" =  1,
                                 "Medicare" = 2,
                                 "National defense" = 3,
                                 "Social Security" = 4
                     ), selected = 99, width = "100%"),
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `sample()`:

```
library(shiny)

knowledge1_choices <- 
  c("Foreign aid" =  1,
    "Medicare" = 2,
    "National defense" = 3,
    "Social Security" = 4
  )

ui <- fluidPage(

  radioButtons("knowledge1", 
               label = "On which of the following the does the U.S. federal government currently spend the least?",
               choices = knowledge1_choices[sample(knowledge1_choices)],
               selected = 99,
               width = "100%"),
)

server <- function(input,output,session){
  

}

shinyApp(ui,server)
```